# Подключение Vulkan API к проекту Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, vulkan

Мне известно два способа:
 1. В настройках проекта добавить соответствующие пути к Vulkan (в таком случае при загрузке с Git проект не скомпилируется)
 2. Скопировать в корень проекта папку vulkan и библиотеку vulkan-1.lib
Вопрос: Какой из вариантов более грамотный (правильный)? Или есть другие способы?

Comment: 1 вариант более грамотный и вовсе не подразумевает, что *"при загрузке с Git проект не скомпилируется"*.

Comment: всегда можно сделать либо инструкцию, либо скрипт конфигурации, либо обучить cmake (другую любимую систему сборки) как искать и где.